# While scrolling RecyclerView CoordinatorLayout is shown

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, material-design, android-recyclerview

I have implemented an activity with two slides, the slides content is a fragment with RecyclerView that loads data from my server and creates a GridLayout with images (like in image gallery).

I have added the behavior of scrolling so when you scroll you don't see the toolbar.

My problem is that when the activity starts with the fragment the toolbar is half hidden and when i continue to scroll down and the toolbar is completely hidden the CoordinatorLayout from under is exposed so i get this thing: [image: Image visualizing my description]

as you can see the light green is the CoordinatorLayout and the red is the ViewPager and what i want to achieve is that when you scroll more you will only see the red background and never the green one.

My activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backgroundGray"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/appGreen"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <com.apps.haver.getout.libs.view.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/actionBarTitleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Get Out"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            app:fontName="Peterbuilt.ttf" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#565654"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <com.apps.haver.getout.libs.slider.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/normal_row"
            android:background="@color/appGreen"
            android:elevation="2dp" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#e90f0f" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And my fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.apps.haver.getout.FriendsFragment">


<com.apps.haver.getout.libs.view.AutofitRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:columnWidth="102dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pressToRetryPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPressToRetry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/press_to_retry"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    layout="@layout/loading_template"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

How can I make the toolbar to hide when I am scrolling but still see the RecyclerView content on my entire screen?

Thanks...